# Pandas error - "ValueError: labels ['attributes'] not contained in axis"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am extracting data from Saleforce system and converting it to a `Dataframe` when I get an error:

```
ValueError: labels ['attributes'] not contained in axis.
```

Given below is my Python script:

```
raw = sf_data_cursor.bulk.Case.query('''SELECT Id, Status, AccountName__c, AccountId FROM Case''')

raw_df = pd.DataFrame(raw).drop('attributes', axis= 1,inplace=False)
```

Could anyone assist.

Comment: can you show how your raw data looks like, also provide a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, this error occurs if the column (in this case `attributes`) you're trying to drop from `raw` doesn't exist.

Try the code: `raw.columns`, and the output should include the column name you're trying to drop.